# Java Class Variables & __init__ method in Python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

I've coded in Java a long ago, I remember how the class keyword could be accessible inside any method in the class,

Example,

```
int age
int xyz

public void abc(int aga,int xyz) {
    this.age = age;
    this.xyz = xyz;
}
```

Now in above code, 
`this.age` and `this.xyz` are referencing to the class variable.
These two variables are class variable and have declared outside the method `abc`, 
therefore,these two variables could be accessible anywhere in  the class.

Now if we talk about Python,

the `__init__` method in Python is a construct,
If I declare any variable inside the `__init__`, would that be accessible anywhere in its Class, - even though it is declared inside a method -  just like Java class variables ?

for example, 
Consider this code,

```
Class Main:
     def __init__(self):
           self._age = None
           self._xyz = None
```

The variables `age` and `xyz` are declared inside `__init__` , can i access them in other methods of the class `Main` ?
I may know the Answer is Yes, but Why the answer is Yes ?
The variables are declared inside a method and not declared as class variable then how could they be accessed by other methods and other classes.

Comment: Have you tried it out?

Comment: Yes I've tried it this is why I am asking..because in java, this variable is used when we access class variable but in python there is no need to write self in the above code. In my code (that i am studying) , variables age and xyz have never declared in a class (only declared inside __init__) but they are accessed in other classes.

Comment: Yes you can. Just reference it as `self._age`

Comment: or even `Main()._age` if you wanted ... although _ typically denotes protected ... that is only by convention ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the attributes named in [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) are instance attributes.  This means that, upon creating an instance of the class, they become available to that instance.

You can reference them through `self` (same as `this` in Java) by doing `self.<attribute>`.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> class Main:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._age = None
...         self._xyz = None
...     def method(self):
...         print self._age, self._xyz
...
>>> test = Main()
>>> test.method()
None None
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Defining things in `__init__` as `self.xxx` makes them instance attributes. In Python, class attributes are simply defined on the class, outside a method.

```
class MyClass(object):

    abc = 0
    xyz = 42

    def __init__(...)
        # and so on
```

These can be reached inside any method using e.g. `self.abc` as long as there is not also an instance attribute named `abc`. If there is, the instance attribute takes priority. You can access the class attribute even in this case using `type(self).abc`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python a class is an object and "class attribute" really means attributes of the class object itself - not of instances of the class. Now Python objects structure is dynamic - you can add (or remove) attributes anywhere (yes, even outside methods) on a per-instance basis - while Java class have a fixed, declared structure, which is why in Java you have to declare the structure of the class (which attributes it will have) in the class statement's body, while in Python you usually do so in the initializer.